# Macro to automatically generate section numbers

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

I am struggling with creating a macro to automatically generate section number and subsection numbers. I had thought the snippet below would work but it is failing to assign the value if not already set. I am sure this is obvious but my lack of jinja experience is showing... or perhaps lack of Python experience... or both!

I get this error.

```
{% set sectionnumber.value = sectionnumber.value + 1 %}
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateRuntimeError: cannot assign attribute on non-namespace object
```

```
{% macro getsectionnumber(type) -%}

  {% if subsectionnumber is none %}
    {% if sectionnumber is none  %}
      {% set sectionnumber = namespace(value=0) %}
    {% endif %}
    {% set subsectionnumber = namespace(value=0) %}
  {% endif %}

  {% if type == 'section' %}
    {% if sectionnumber is none  %}
      {% set sectionnumber = namespace(value=0) %}
    {% endif %}
    {% set sectionnumber.value = sectionnumber.value + 1 %}
    {{ sectionnumber.value }}
  {% endif %}

  {% if type == 'subsection' %}
    {% set subsectionnumber.value = subsectionnumber.value + 1 %}
    {{ sectionnumber.value }}.{{ subsectionnumber.value }}
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my template:

```
template = """
{% set sectionnumber = namespace(value=0) %}
{% set subsectionnumber = namespace(value=0) %}
{% macro getsectionnumber(type) -%}
  {% if type == 'section' %}
    {% set sectionnumber.value = sectionnumber.value + 1 %}
    {{ sectionnumber.value }}
  {% endif %}    
  {% if type == 'subsection' %}
    {% set subsectionnumber.value = subsectionnumber.value + 1 %}
    {{ sectionnumber.value }}.{{ subsectionnumber.value }}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{{ getsectionnumber('section') }}
{{ getsectionnumber('subsection') }}
{{ getsectionnumber('subsection') }}
{{ getsectionnumber('section') }}
{{ getsectionnumber('subsection') }}
{{ getsectionnumber('subsection') }}
    """
```

print the template:

```
print(Template(template).render())
```

result:

```
1
 
1.1

1.2

2

2.3

2.4
```